# Can't use any modules which I have just installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I've already installed some modules like pyperclip or watchdog but it seems like every time I try to import these, the Program I'm writing just can't find the path to the modules which are saved in a subfolder of the main Python38 folder.

I already checked for the right Interpreter and the right version of Python. I have the right version installed/selected as interpreter and it's the only one on my system (3.8.2).

How can I access/import these modules to my program now?

Comment: check if the folder containing your modules is in the list of directory present in `sys.path`

Comment: Nevermind, you were right, I had the wrong folder for PYTHONPATH selected under my variables, now it has the site-package folder in sys.path and now my modules seem to work, thank you for your tip!